# Can’t able to access kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am able to connect elasticsearch. However, I am **unable** to access kibana on 5601. Can anyone please help out this to work? Thanks in advance.

In the kibana.yml file, I have modified the server.host parameter to point to my domain.

- Elasticsearch Version: 7.7.0
- Kibana Version: kibana-7.7.0-1.x86_64
- OS: Centos 7
- JAVA Version: 11

kibana.yml

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "my_domain"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://my_domain:9200"]
```

Kibana Logs

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-02T14:08:03Z","tags":["warning","plugins-discovery"],"pid":2844,"message":"Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: apm_oss"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-02T14:08:03Z","tags":["warning","plugins-discovery"],"pid":2844,"message":"Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: file_upload"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-02T14:08:03Z","tags":["warning","plugins-discovery"],"pid":2844,"message":"Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: triggers_actions_ui"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-02T14:08:09Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":2844,"message":"Plugin \"infra\" has been disabled since some of its direct or transitive dependencies are missing or disabled."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-02T14:08:27Z","tags":["warning","plugins-discovery"],"pid":2941,"message":"Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: apm_oss"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-02T14:08:27Z","tags":["warning","plugins-discovery"],"pid":2941,"message":"Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: file_upload"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-02T14:08:27Z","tags":["warning","plugins-discovery"],"pid":2941,"message":"Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: triggers_actions_ui"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-02T14:08:32Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":2941,"message":"Plugin \"infra\" has been disabled since some of its direct or transitive dependencies are missing or disabled."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-06-02T14:08:35Z","tags":["fatal","root"],"pid":2941,"message":"{ Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available localhost:5601\n    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1263:19)\n    at listenInCluster (net.js:1328:12)\n    at doListen (net.js:1461:7)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)\n  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',\n  errno: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',\n  syscall: 'listen',\n  address: 'localhost',\n  port: 5601 }"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kibana runs on port **5601** by default. This error message says that, when Kibana tried to start up & bind to port 5601, it couldn't because something else was already bound to port 5601.

> Check if some application is already bound to port 5601. If yes, Try
>   another port.

If No, Then It would be easy to investigate the issue, if you could attach the contents of your /etc/hosts file.